# About Stack Frame

Tags: c, gdb, stack

I learn about stack frame. But if I'm right, before function is called, that function's arguments are pushed into stack frame.

For example,

```
int main(void)
{
  printf("hi everyone %d \n", 3);
  return 0;
}
```

In this case, in the main stack frame, "Hi everyone %d \n" 's address, and 3 should be pushed and then printf must be called, if i'm right.

But there is no such instruction when I use gdb.

I'm studying about String Format Vulnerability. But what I write above didn't happen. What's wrong with me?

Comment: What are the produced instructions?

Comment: What do you mean by "But there is no such instruction" ? Such what instruction ?

Comment: It depends on the architecture binary interface (ABI) and the calling convention (which will be the cdecl calling convention in this case). The first few arguments of a particular type may be passed in registers instead of the stack. For example, the System V AMD64 ABI passes the first six integer or pointer arguments, and the first eight floating point arguments in registers.

Comment: I mean on format string vulnerability, before printf is called, there should be arguments passed to printf. But no arguments are in the main stack frame. How can I find the %s %d 's address which has real value.

Comment: @A.Cho what architecture (OS / processor) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article about how the [GCC compiler can optimize code to replace some types of call with equivalent, but not identical, operations](http://www.ciselant.de/projects/gcc_printf/gcc_printf.html) may help.

The example you gave would be a prime target for this sort of optimization.

Comment: Only the simple usages of `printf` get optimized. The OP's example is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

For your simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hi everyone %d \n", 3);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled as `gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall test.c -o test` (on an Ubuntu 14.04 system using gcc version 4.8.4) it appears that the parameters to `printf` are being passed in registers.  Setting a break point on the `printf` command and disassembling yields the following:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000040052d <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000000000040052e <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
=> 0x0000000000400531 <+4>:     mov    esi,0x3
   0x0000000000400536 <+9>:     mov    edi,0x4005d4
   0x000000000040053b <+14>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000400540 <+19>:    call   0x400410 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400545 <+24>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000000000040054a <+29>:    pop    rbp
   0x000000000040054b <+30>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

We can see that the value 3 (which in this case is encoded into the instruction as a literal) is begin moved into the `%esi` register and your string's address is being moved into the `%edi` register.  You can verify this by looking at the memory:

```
(gdb) x/16cb 0x4005d4
0x4005d4:   104 'h' 105 'i' 32 ' '  101 'e' 118 'v' 101 'e' 114 'r' 121 'y'
0x4005dc:   111 'o' 110 'n' 101 'e' 32 ' '  37 '%'  100 'd' 32 ' '  10 '\n
```

Also, you can examine the stack and base pointers, and you will notice that in this simple program the stack is not used:

```
(gdb) print $rbp
$4 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe460
(gdb) print $rsp
$5 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe460
```

as `$rpb` and `$rsp` both have the same value.

Hope this helps.
-T.

Answer (score -1):

Following the `__cdecl` calling convention (the default for most compilers) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl we can see what the compiler might produce.

First the caller makes a stack frame.

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
```

What the above code does is simple. First it pushes the current value of ebp to the stack, then it moves the value of the stack pointer to ebp.

Now it pushes the function's arguments to the stack from right to left.

```
push    3; The number
push    ?; Placeholder for the pointer to the string
```

Now it calls the function.

```
call    ?; Placeholder for the address of printf
```

When the function returns we clean the stack by simply resetting the stack frame

```
mov esp, ebp
```

and restoring ebp

```
pop ebp
```

Just looking at some of the code that visual studio 2015 produced for me I can confirm there are variations to this calling convention, but this is the general idea of stack frames.

Comment: Typical ABIs on x86 and ARM and many other architectures use different conventions. Also Linux and Windows have different conventions on x86 and ARM, too. x86/x64 add even more complexity.